# Django Rest Framework: How to save a field as an object of a different model, then return the key to the original model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Sorry for the weird title.

I have 2 models:

```
class TranslationWord(models.Model):
    translation = models.TextField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class TranslationByUser(models.Model):
    synset = models.ForeignKey(Synset)    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)    
    translation = models.ForeignKey(TranslationWord)
```

The first one is supposed to basically just save words. The second is supposed to get a user's input. If the word exists in the first class, the foreign key value is simply stored. If it doesn't exist, I want to first create an instance of the TranslationWord, and then add the foreign key to the second class.

I'm doing all this with the Django Rest Framework, so I'm pretty stumped.

Currently, I've got these 2 models, 2 serializers (both just instances of ModelSerializer), and a view to save it (ListCreateAPIView).

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input you are expecting? And the code you have tried so far for the view?

Comment: Basically, i want to send some text into the Translation field. Unfortunately, this is actually a foreign key field so I don't know if this approach is even correct anymore. The JSON looks like this: `{
    "synset": 11, 
    "translation": "Something" 
}` and GETting the view would return `{
    "synset": 11, 
    "translation": 1 
}`, for example.

Comment: Would creating a write-only, non-model/non-database field just for getting the translation text be a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

These are basically the steps for creating a successfully validated object in a ModelViewSet create method (it's defined in CreateModelMixin):

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    self.pre_save(serializer.object)
    self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
    self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    headers=headers)
```

It means you can override pre_save for your action in your ViewSet for TranslationByUser, setting attributes as side-effects in the object:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    #get your_translation_word from obj or self.kwargs
    your_translation_word = get_translation_word()
    translation = TranslationWord(translation=your_translation_word)
    translation.save()
    setattr(obj, 'translation', translation)

    #if you also want to support Update, call super method 
    super(TranslationByUserViewSet, self).pre_save(obj)
```

Another thing you can try is to define TranslationWordSerializer as a nested field in TranslationByUserSerializer. This topic is explained in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#dealing-with-nested-objects). Not sure if DRF handles everything about the creation though. I've only tested this behaviour with Multi-table Inheritance (and it works).

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, for anyone who is curious, I created a write-only field in the Serializer, and used it to create the instance in the restore_object method.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=False)
    translation = TranslationLemmaSerializer(required=False)
    translation_text = serializers.WritableField(required=False, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TranslationByUser
        fields = ('id','user','synset', 'translation', 'translation_text',)
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at',)

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        print attrs
        if instance is not None:
            instance.synset = attrs.get('synset', instance.synset)
            return instance

        translation_text = attrs.get('translation_text')
        del attrs['translation_text'] #delete non-model attribute before actually creating it

        translationHIT = TranslationByUser(**attrs) #create model here
        translation_id = None
        try:
            translation_instance = TranslationWord.objects.get(translation=translation_text) #check if translationWord is already present
        except:
            translation_instance = TranslationWord(translation=translation_text)
            translation_instance.save() #otherwise, create it
        TranslationByUser.translation = translation_instance
        print attrs
        return TranslationByUser

    def get_validation_exclusions(self,instance=None):
        exclusions = super(MySerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()
        return exclusions + ['user', 'translation']
```